# Invoke-Restmethod returning text/html when expecting json with Powershell

Tags: powershell, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

Command being used:

```
$Tenant = "tentant_id"
$ClientID = "application_id"
$ClientSecret = "application_password"
$Url = "http://login.microsoftonline.com/$Tenant/oauth2/v2.0/token"

$Body = @{
  'client_id' = $ClientID
  'scope' = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
  'client_secret' = $ClientSecret
  'grant_type' = 'client_credentials'
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $Url -Body $Body -Verbose
```

Actual Result:

```
VERBOSE: POST http://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token with -1-byte payload
VERBOSE: received 17293-byte response of content type text/html; charset=utf-8

html
----
html
```

Expected Result:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "ext_expires_in": 0,
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q......."
}
```

Is there something that I'm missing? For some reason when using the above code in Powershell it's returning some sort of webpage, when it should give the token. Using the Chrome extension [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) I was able to construct a POST request using the same url, and client id, scope, client secret and grant type in the body which gives the correct response. Using the access token from that, I can then use the following to get a proper response back:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $AccessToken"} -Uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/jsmith@example.com
```

Here's a link to pastebin for the output of $HtmlObject | format-list *
https://pastebin.com/KMMKDGut
As it's too large to format as code here.

Comment: You're not specifying a `-ContentType`, fyi.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 According to the [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-5.1) page when the method is Post, content type is set to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". I tried adding it just for fun and gets the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you get back an HTML response to a JSON or SOAP call, it means that IIS was really upset and is returning back an IIS/ASP.net error page.  In that case, you typically need to look at the event logs on the server itself to figure out why IIS/ASP.Net was upset.

Comment: Looking at the object that is produced, it might be a log in page. I'm not sure why that would be though since I have already authenticated this app and am using the /token endpoint which isn't supposed to ask for any credentials. Also since this is a Microsoft site, I'm not sure how I'd be able to access any logs.

Comment: Can you add the actual HTML that is returned? It may provide a hint at what is going on.

Comment: Oddly the message your getting is an error: `AADSTS90056: This endpoint only accepts POST, OPTIONS requests. Received a GET request.`. You may want to use Fiddler to see what is actually getting passed back and forth here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion by Marc LaFleur, I took a look at the request with Fiddler. It showed the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://login.microsoftonline.com:443/clientID/oauth2/v2.0/token
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
client-request-id: 1d918059-ab39-4d41-8191-b0416d4f03f4
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 10 Jan 2018 21:52:51 GMT
Content-Length: 209

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://login.microsoftonline.com:443/clientID/oauth2/v2.0/token">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Apparently all I had to do was change the original URL to https so that it doesn't have to redirect. Not sure what was happening in the Html object returned though and why I wasn't seeing that in Fiddler.

Comment: The html object is literally the html at the bottom of your codeblock.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 The block posted here is output from Fiddler. The original object is the pastebin in the op.